# Error while making a while loop program in MARS ".asciiz is not a valid integer constant or label"

Tags: assembly, mips, mips32, mars-simulator

I downloaded MARS on my Mac (already installed jdk) to run some MIPS code and I'm getting a weird error: ".asciiz is not a valid integer constant or label".

I'm following this tutorial: 
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0aexcR9CNcE

I've tried to debug it by changing the quotes (maybe that solves it?) and looked up in the internet to find similar error.

```
.data
    message .asciiz "While loop completed"
    space .asciiz " ,"

.text
main:
#i=0

addi $t0, $zero, 1

while:
    bgt $t0, 10, exit
    jal printNumber
    addi $t0, $t0, 1    #i++

    j while         #jump back to the while loop

exit:
li $v0, 4
la $a0, message
syscall



#end of program 
li $v0, 10 
syscall

printNumber:
    li $v0, 1
    add $a0, $t0, $zero
    syscall

    li $v0, 4
    la $a0, space
    syscall

    jr $ra
```

This is what I got back:

Error in /Users/shivanshsuhane/Desktop/while_loop.asm line 2 column 10: ".asciiz" is not a valid integer constant or label

Error in /Users/shivanshsuhane/Desktop/while_loop.asm line 2 column 18: ""While loop completed"" is not a valid integer constant or label

Error in /Users/shivanshsuhane/Desktop/while_loop.asm line 3 column 8: ".asciiz" is not a valid integer constant or label

Error in /Users/shivanshsuhane/Desktop/while_loop.asm line 3 column 16: "" ,"" is not a valid integer constant or label

Error in /Users/shivanshsuhane/Desktop/while_loop.asm line 2 column 2: Symbol "message" not found in symbol table.

Error in /Users/shivanshsuhane/Desktop/while_loop.asm line 3 column 2: Symbol "space" not found in symbol table.

Assemble: operation completed with errors.

I expected a list of integers till 10, separated by commas.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `message:` and `space:` to separate the label from the directive.

MARS's built-in assembler doesn't parse it otherwise; I think it's treating `message` as an instruction if there's no `:` to make it a label.

I tried in MARS and I can reproduce your error without the `:` characters.  This *does* assemble fine:

```
.data
    message: .asciiz "While loop completed"
    space:   .asciiz " ,"
```

Comment: Thank you so much, I can't believe I missed that